# check datetime in sql before execute a function

Tags: php, mysql, function, datetime

Ok I got information in the Mysql database table with a datetime colomn.
I got also a php function to excecute and fill this table with an entry.

What I want is to check the date in the column. If it is a month or some days old. The php function excecute and update the table entry with new info.  If the date is less then a month old. Another function will be excecute and only get the info from the database without updating it.

So

```
if ($datetimeCheck) {
    // function 1
} else {
    // function 2
}
```

How does this check looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Although you did *not* include 'what you tried' so far, a pointer that may help you;

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: Well it should be something like this  $sid = SPRequest::sid(); // $sid is id of sobipro entry  
 $time1 = SPFactory::db()->select( 'createdtime', '#__sobipro_field_api', array(  'sid' => $sid ))->loadResult();
    $timeFromMysql = strtotime($time1);
 $time = SPRequest::now();

if (abs($timeFromMysql - $time) > 30*24*60*60) {

Answer (score 0):

It should be somehing like this

```
        $sid = SPRequest::sid(); // $sid is id of sobipro entry  
    $time1 = SPFactory::db()->select( 'createdtime', '#__sobipro_field_api', array(  'sid' => $sid ))->loadResult();
    $timeFromMysql = strtotime($time1);
    $time = SPRequest::now();
if (abs($timeFromMysql - $time) > 30*24*60*60) {
```

Comment: Is this part of your question? If so, please press the 'edit' button below the question and append it. Also, I'm not sure what the question actually is; does this code work? Are you having problems with this code? Are you requesting suggestions on optimization?